Custom URL structure
I have several subpages and over 100 posts in WordPress.
Their structure is standard and looks like this:
example.com/contact
example.com/about
example.com/post1
example.com/post2

Now I need to add a parameter to the URL with the dealer's name
example.com/dealerXXX
example.com/dealerYYY

and here is the problem, the dealer should have all available subpages and posts
example.com/dealerXXX/contact
example.com/dealerXXX/about
example.com/dealerXXX/post1
example.com/dealerXXX/post2

example.com/dealerYYY/contact
example.com/dealerYYY/about
example.com/dealerYYY/post1
example.com/dealerYYY/post2

How to achieve this effect in WP?

It sounds like you're looking for the Rewrite API.
